# MICROSOFT ODBC - ADO string portability (VBA) on Windows 10_64 bits , Excel_64 bits , ODBC_64 bits

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, 32bit-64bit, adodb

I have been asked to check at an issue on an "old" excel file, that have been moved to a new server and which is "no more working".
Before I was granted to access on the new server, I have tested on my laptop (Win10/office 64/oracle client 64/ODBC 64).

The VBA connection string is :

```
strConOracle = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP) 
strConOracle = strConOracle & "(HOST=" & HOST & ")(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=" & DATABASE
strConOracle = strConOracle & "))); uid=" & USER & " ;pwd=" & PASSWORD & ";"
Set oConOracle = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set oRsOracle = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
```

After several tests, I think , I have understood that the string "**{Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}**" refers to an ODBC 32bits pilot. In my 64bits ODBC, the name is "**Oracle in OraClient19Home1**".
If I just change `{Microsoft ODBC for Oracle} by {Oracle in OraClient19Home1}` , it's not working (too quick to win :) )

So I'm just wondering If you know if ADODB connection is still possible on a 64 bits ?
And if there's some tricky thing we got to add in the VBA code.

Yes, I know there's a feature in excel called "getdata" that use external ODBC DSN connection, but it's too invasive. It needs to rework all the mechanism of the VBA code, and it's too long.
So I first want to check at VBA ADO connections.

Just for information , when I finally get in the issuing server *(Windows Server® 2008 Standard/Office 32bits/Oracle 32bits/ODBC 32bits)*. I just need to add some trusted locations and buttons in FORM mode to get it work back again. I guess that's because in the **ODBC 32bits**, there is a pilot called "**Microsoft ODBC for Oracle**" or because there's a **registry keys** at this name :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\Microsoft ODBC for Oracle]
```

But I feel that, one day we won't be able to work in 32bits.
And it's may be a good warning for upgrading to 64bits.

regards
G